# result of an oracle command

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a graphical user interface using Windows Form Application, using an oracle database.
I'm trying to bind to a label in my UI the result of an oracle command. 
This is my code :

```
            OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            string city = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
           cmd.CommandText ="select c.companynum,c.namec from flight f, company c where f.companynum=c.companynum AND f.name1=&param1 order by f.name1;";  
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", city);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleType.VarChar, 200);
           cmd.Parameters["result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
             try
             {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (cmd.Parameters["result"].Value.ToString() == "")
                    label2.Text = "No destinations.";
                else
                    label2.Text = cmd.Parameters["result"].Value.ToString();
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Caught");
             }
```

But when it runs there's an exception : ORA-01036 : illegal variable name/number.

I don't know how to fix my code ? 
NB : For my homework I have to use here the '&' method.

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery command is for updating a SQL table, use a dataset and your data adapter for getting the data (or a data reader).

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is done a little misunderstanding.. :)

I think that the original trace of your homework intended to that it should create a stored procedure where put into the select sql statement that you have passed to the command.

Stored proc should have 2 parameters: "city" and "result" ;)

Good homework!